# Meteor project not deploying to android because it can't install a cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

-I get this error when trying to deploy a simple meteor project (I'm trying to make a soundboard) to my android device on windows.

-The sound works on the browser build

-I wasn't getting this error message before the app could actually play sound

-I've tried meteor reset and removing the android platform and adding it again

-I've tried adding the cordova plugin manually using meteor add, but I'm not sure I'm getting the syntax right or even know the right plugin on git (I've been trying to add this one: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio)

This is the full error readout:

```
C:\Users\redacted\Documents\aaaaAppDev\Meteor\soundboardtest>meteor run android-device
[[[[[ C:\Users\redacted\Documents\aaaaAppDev\Meteor\soundboardtest ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While adding plugin com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.lowlatencyaudio@1.0.0 to Cordova project:
   Cordova error: Failed to fetch plugin com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.lowlatencyaudio@1.0.0 via registry.
   Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
   Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
   Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.lowlatencyaudio
   (If the error message contains suggestions for a fix, note that this may not apply to the Meteor integration.
   You can try running again with the --verbose option to help diagnose the issue.)

C:\Users\redacted\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.0_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\cordova-support\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:116
  throw error;
        ^
ExitWithCode:1
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to add the package. Are you specifically needing 1.0.0 might be worth trying with version @3.0.7 as that's the current version on the module

Comment: Do you mean when I used the command "meteor add cordova:com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.lowlatencyaudio@3.0.7"? (I tried doing that before your comment with 1.0.0 because when I was googling that plugin, it said that the version number was 1.0). I just tried the same thing with 3.0.7 and got the same error. EDIT: I should mention it tried to add it automatically before I tried manually. It defaulted to 1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

So since the app was still small, I just created a new project and copied all of the code to the new one. I never did anything with "meteor add" in this new project, but it actually deployed to android.

I have a new problem that the audio won't play in the android version, but that seems like a different issue so I'm going to declare this one solved.